# How to use click() on more then one element with the same XPath?

Tags: python, selenium

In my project, I want to use `click()` on a list with buttons. They all have the same xpath. But when I run through the list I scraped with seleniums `driver.find_elements_by_xpath()`. I just click on the first one and then the for loop breaks.

Don't know if I approach it the wrong way.

Code:

```
driver.get(url)  
try:
    myElem = None 
    myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@href ='javascript:;']")))
    
    if myElem != None:
        buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href ='javascript:;']").click()
        for button in buttons:
            button.click()
```

HTML:

```
<a class="open" data-path="/public/employees/767772/description.json" href="javascript:;">
                <span class="icon-caret-right"></span> 続きを読む
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use List in selenium

```
List<WebElement> LIST = driver.findElements(By.xpath(""));
    LIST.get(0).click();
```

first you need to store all clicks in list then if you want click first click you can do that with **LIST.get(0).click();**`

Comment: I just get a error: "can't assign to comparison"  on the "List"

Comment: @JengaSneaky can you share or ask question in stackoverflow with your code snipet and details ?

Answer (score 0):

This line is your problem:

```
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href ='javascript:;']").click()
```

You're doing `find_elements` but because of the `click()` at the end you're clicking on the first item then returning the response from the `click()` into `buttons`. That means `buttons` is not a list or array. I don't think anything returns from a `click()` so when you try to iterate through, you have nothing to iterate on.

Your code is mostly right If you drop the `.click()` on that line you will get a list and then you can iterate through:

```
        buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href ='javascript:;']")
        for button in buttons:
            button.click()
```

This pretty much is the solution provided by @JustinLambert - but i think he's provided an example in the a different language.

In Python you don't need to worry about declaring it as a `List<T>` - just assign it to a variable as you already have done.

Comment: the problem I'm getting now, it's like click() breaks the for a loop. I look at the loop and it goes through all the buttons but when I use click() it just clicks on the first one.

Comment: @JengaSneaky can you please be more accurate? What does "breaks"  mean? Is there an error?  Does clicking your links change the page? Have you debugged it to look at your runtime values?... Since you haven't shared your url I can't test it,. You need to provide detail for anyone to solve your problem